How to add custom Block at Shipping Method Select in Magento 1
I want to add custom block below shipping methods and this custom block should be inside of shipping method form. I think following line of code is helpful for adding this. but no idea how to proceed.
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

Referring how-to-add-custom-block-at-shipping-methods-below-in-onepage-checkout but I need it in Magento 1

Magento1 have diffrent structure then magento2.

Can I achieve this in Magento 1?

Yes you can added easily into magento1

Please guide me how to do it

You can try the steps describe below to add a block in checkout cart page
1.Edit you Magento 1 Theme file checkout.xml. So you need to edit the checkout.xml file under YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/theme /default/layout
    ...........
    ...........
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
                    <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
                </block>                

                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Items Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
                    <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" />                   
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                                 
                <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
                        <!-- Add Custom Block-->
                        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.cart.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/cart/additional-block.phtml"/>
                        <label>Checkout Forms Additional Block</label>
                    </block>      
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Items After</label>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
            <label>Additional Product Info</label>
        </block>
    </checkout_cart_index>


But I did not want to change any core file

@Tareq there is another way to overriding the file using a custom module

@Tareq either create a theme that inherits from core or add a local.xml layout file.

@Tareq
Hey,
You can check the below given references to add custom block at checkout page in Magento 1.9, where shipping method related block/phtml was called, so you can find that reference into xml file and use it.
Magento 1.9 : Add Block to One step checkout
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329649/magento-insert-static-block-into-the-progress-block-of-the-onepage-checkout
Thank You!
